# SMTP/HTTP/FTP status check using PHP

Tags: php, ftp, smtp

I am in need of a piece of code to check whether the website is alive or down . I think this can be done with php curl or fsockopen . But i do want to check whether other services like ftp, smtp, https, mysql, etc are up or down . Can anyone tell a method to implement this using php . I have one site to monitor continuously but need a simple script only .

Answer (score 1):

Marek is correct - you should be looking at something a bit more sophisticated.

You've already got multiple services to check - and you'll need a mechanism for scheduling those checks - and you'll need a mechanism for reporting problems - and pretty soon you'll wish you had some sort of retention mechanism to establish baselines and trends.

There are some companies offering very basic protocol level checks for a site (many of whom probably use nagios to implement this). You are possibly still at the borderline of whether its more effective to just use such a service or bite the bullet and implement your own monitoring. The one route I would *strongly* recommend you do NOT take is to try and write your own maonitoring platform - regardless of how simple your requirements seem to be.

You don't necesarily need to use NRPE - nagios (and most monitoring solutions) allow you to configure (and write) simple scripts to run at intervals and collate the results. There are lots of pre-written scripts available. And implementing your own is very simple:

```
<?php

$started=microtime(true);
if ($page=file_get_contents($argv[1])) {
   if (0.5<(microtime()-$started) && strstr($file, 'some string from page')) {
       print "OK";
       exit 0;
   } else if (strstr($file, 'some string from page')) {
       print "WARNING";
       exit 1;
   }
   print "CRITICAL";
   exit 2;
}
print "UNKNOWN";
exit 3;
```

(there are much better scripts than this bundled in the standard set of monitors).

Answer (score 0):

You can use part of nagios called nagios-nrpe and connect to it using PHP:

http://blog.cactiusers.org/2012/02/18/nagios-nrpe-client-via-php/

Comment: Yes i agree, but i need to find a native mechanism available with PHP to do the same . I have seen fsockopen is a way to connect to different ports, can we depend on it or not to check SMTP,FTP< or other port oriented services running on a server .

Comment: For instance i have a 25 port on Ip 192.168.1.23 ,running an SMTP service, i need to script to check whether smtp is running on this port or not. Using php . Also if the service is running, even through there is a chance of firewall reject the connection, so it can be also tracked .